# audio, FFT not working

Tags: c#, audio, aforge

```
class Main
{

    WaveFileReader reader;
    short[] sample;
    Complex[] tmpComplexArray;

    public Main()
    {

        //read in wav, to raw data in byte array then to short array.
        reader = new WaveFileReader("C:\\Users\\minford\\Downloads\\English_Subtitles_.wav");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
        reader.Read(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
        sample = new short[reader.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n += 2)
        {
            sample[n] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, n);

        }




        // short array to complex
       Complex[] complexData = new Complex[sample.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
        {
            Complex tmp = new Complex(sample[i],0);

            complexData[i] = tmp;


        }

        //to get first 500 for testing.
        tmpComplexArray = new Complex[500];
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
           Complex a = new Complex(complexData[i]);
           tmpComplexArray[i] = a;
        }
        //run FFT
        FourierTransform.DFT(tmpComplexArray ,FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

        //print result
        for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(complexData[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

I have this problem while using the FFT from AForge. Is this the correct way of using it? the complex numbers that get returned(only returning the first 500 at the moment) have the second number as 0 every time.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the wrong data:

```
    //print result      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpComplexArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(tmpComplexArray[i]);
    }
```